# How to set equal width to multiple textviews irrespective of word count aligned vertically in android?

Tags: android, text-alignment, richtext, text-formatting, text-styling

As you can see in attached images, line 1 has two words, line 2 has 4 words and last line has one word. 
But they all have equal width irrespective of different text size and word count.Can anyone help me to achieve this? [image]

Answer (score 0):

use `AppCompatTextView`and set `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` , `android:maxLines="1"`

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="400dp" <!--fixed size-->
        android:layout_height="200dp" <!--fixed size-->
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: I have tried above code for achieving the thing, it didn't worked out. Can you help with the solution?

Comment: @JohnSmith what is the value of `width` and `height` in your TextView ?

Comment: <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />

Comment: @JohnSmith set `height` to higher value